# Anomaly Detection On Sensor Signals

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset that consists of only one column. This column holds values of signal strength between two devices. Sometimes, the signal is disrupted. I need to find the starting index of anomaly and for how many points it is anomalous (there are multiple occasions of disturbances in the dataset). Dataset doesn't have timestamps so I'm only using indexes.

I tried three-sigma rule to find anomalies but it wasn't very effective. For example, points 101, 102, 105, 108, 109, 112, 115 and 116 are detected as anomalies. In this case, the anomalous period starts at index 101 and continues until 116 (16 points). However, this approach doesn't recognize some points in between as anomalies although they should be.

What kind of approach could I use?

Comment: I think this goes outside what you can answer with *statistics*, per se; it depends a lot on your model for how the data are generated and what the contributors to anomaly might be. For neurophysiology, for example, this is still an unsolved problem and one that many labs still address manually, as hard as that is to believe. Personally I prefer algorithmic solutions even if they are not quite as good, but these are generally pretty ad hoc.

Comment: When I look at the problem, it looks like the solution should be pretty simple but I couldn't think of an effective way to solve this. When I plot the data, it is easy to see where the anomalies are. I also tried to plot the standard deviation of all the consecutive couples of data but I can't be sure if calculating standard deviation of 2 values and saying "these 2 points' standard deviation is higher than the usual so there should be an anomaly between the 2".

Answer (score 1):

you need a simple regime switching. the problem with your current approach is you mark anomalies only relative to normal. as a result you snap back to normal too easily. You need to mark relative to a current regime.

for instance, suppose your sigma is 100, and your data is x=10,20,30,400,200,350,20,50

Your current algo marks 400 and 500 as anomalies, not 200 because it's with 3 sigma from normal level. Instead, if you assume that at 400 the level switched, then 200 is still within this new level, which continues through 350 then drops to 20.

Comment: A Hidden Markov Model with two states could be one such method.

Comment: A related way is to use different thresholds to enter an anomaly state, than to leave it. This is known as hysteresis in control theory etc.